# Curl throwing a 400 Bad request error when using POST to gitlab from command line

Tags: curl, gitlab

When i try to push a jar file to gitlab using curl post command, i'm getting a 400 Bad request error.
This is happening only for Jar files. I'm able to push the text & json files successfully.
I'm using the below command to post the files.

```
curl -v --request POST \
--header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:<token provided>" \
--form "branch=develop" \
--form "commit_message=<message provide>" \
--form "action[][action]=create" \
--form "action[][file_path]=<path provided> \
--form "action[][content]=<app.jar" \
"https://registry.com/api/v4/projects/111/repository/commits"
```

Please someone tell me what i'm missing here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to POST the binary file to gitlab by encoding the jar/war files using base64 encoding

base64 --wrap 0 app.jar > app.jar

And run the command above.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [possible causes](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/400-bad-request) for an [error 400](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#status.400), a potential reason for your error is a jar file too big:

> The client may be uploading a file that is too large.
> Most web servers or applications have an explicit file size limit that prevents files that are too big from being uploaded and clogging up bandwidth and other resources in the server. In many cases, the server will produce a 400 Bad Request Error when a file is too large (and, thus, the request cannot be completed).

Validate that by trying to commit a *small* jar file, and see if that works in that case.

Comment: I'm trying with 63KB jar file. But still it's not working

Comment: @raki1205 Then, if the size is really not an issue (I would confirm it with a few K jar, less than 10K for instance), check if the network is an issue by trying the same query from different workstations.

Comment: I tried with 4K file. But still no luck. I tried 100MB text file, it worked fine.